# MS Access How to convert this select query to Delete query?

Tags: ms-access

I have the following select query

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.field1=t2.field1 And t1.field2=t2.field2 And t1.field3=t2.field3 ;
```

I want to convert this into a delete query. how should i write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
DELETE 
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.field1=t2.field1 
  And t1.field2=t2.field2 
  And t1.field3=t2.field3
```

Will delete all records in t1 that have a matching record in t2 based on the three field values.

Answer (score 3):

What about this query:

```
DELETE FROM t1
WHERE t1.field1 IN (
  SELECT t1.field1 FROM t1, t2  
  WHERE t1.field1=t2.field1 And
        t1.field2=t2.field2 And
        t1.field3=t2.field3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% on access but does:

```
DELETE t1
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.field1=t2.field1 And t1.field2=t2.field2 And t1.field3=t2.field3 ;
```

Work?

Comment: The FROM clause is not valid for a Jet/SQL DELETE statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM t1
FROM t1 AS tt1, t2 AS tt2
WHERE tt1.field1=tt2.field1 And tt1.field2=tt2.field2 And tt1.field3=tt2.field3 ;
```

EDIT:

Did this in MS Access

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW t1.*
    FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON (t1.field3 = t2.field3) AND (t1.field2 = t2.field2) AND (t1.field1 = t2.field1);
```

And it worked, you have to set the Unique Records to Yes

Comment: Shouldn't "DELETE FROM t1" in the first example be "DELETE FROM tt1"? And what's the purpose of aliasing that makes the table names longer?

Comment: The second answer is the correct one, i left the first one but can remove it

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with something similar.

I found the easiest way is not to use a query at all, but to create an empty duplicate table with multiple Primary Keys with Duplicates OK set (Design View hold down Ctrl key and select the rows you want and then right click and select them all as Primary Keys).

Then copy and paste all the rows from your table into the new table. OK the error messages and you will find you have a table with only unique values in the fields you wanted.

That has the additional benefit of not allowing duplicate rows in your new table.